# Reliable way to use $( document ).ready() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say in the middle of a page generation, e.g. PHP script, you need to attach some code with jQuery' ready, e.g.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "hi!" );
});
```

The problem is, at this point, **you don't know if jQuery has or has not been loaded**, how to modify the above code so **both** cases will be handled?

**Update:** The reason I ask is I want to add some JS codes in a WordPress blog post, but the jQuery is loaded in the footer (which I cannot alter), so I want to reliable solution that work both when jQuery is loaded in the header and footer.

Comment: Try this: if($) { ... }

Comment: Simply don't attach code in the middle of page generation - just include everything at the end. Or, include it after your script tag which imports jQuery. If you include it before it, it will never work. If you include the code after it, it will always work. Simple as that.

Comment: If you're code is inserted after the script importing jQuery, and if you don't explicitly declare the script as asynchronous, then it won't be executed before jQuery is loaded. Does that answer your question ? If not what's your precise use case ?

Comment: The cleanest solution in this case, if you can't afford to wait for the document to be `loaded` might be to emulate $.ready : http://code.google.com/p/domready/

Comment: Use `wp_enqueue_script()` properly and you don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I can only edit the post content, I cannot use any PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only console.log() function inside of document ready :) (I mean no jQuery)

```
if(typeof window.jQuery === "undefined") {
  window.onload = function () {
    console.log("hi!");
  }
} else {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("hi!");
  });
}
```

Else (**UPDATE**)

```
var j = document.createElement('script');
j.type = "text/javascript";
j.url = "url/to/your/jQuery";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(j, s);
/** then your code */
```